# Why am i getting undefined by mapping an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following method in my controller:

```
// @desc   Create a game
// @route  POST /api/games/register
// @access Private

exports.registerGame = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, description, employees, hours } = req.body;

  // Verify that the hours are valid and dont overlap
  const overlappingHours = hours.some((currentHour, currentIndex) => {
    return hours.slice(currentIndex + 1).some((nextHour) => {
      return (
        (currentHour.opening <= nextHour.opening &&
          nextHour.opening < currentHour.closing) ||
        (currentHour.opening < nextHour.closing &&
          nextHour.closing <= currentHour.closing) ||
        (nextHour.opening <= currentHour.opening &&
          currentHour.closing <= nextHour.closing)
      );
    });
  });

  if (overlappingHours) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error: 'Range of hours are overlapping',
    });
  }

  // Verify that the employees exist
  employees.map((employee) => {
    const foundEmployee = Employee.findById(employee);
    console.log(foundEmployee);
    if (!foundEmployee) {
      return next(
        new ErrorResponse(`Employees not found with id of ${employee}`, 404)
      );
    }

    if (foundEmployee.type !== 'manager') {
      return next(new ErrorResponse(`Employees must be managers`, 400));
    }
  });

  console.log(employees);

  const game = await Game.create({
    name,
    description,
    employees,
    hours,
  });

  res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    data: game,
  });
});
```

A Game contains the employees property which is an array of ids that belong to employees.
I am trying to map the employees array and try to find if the id which is a string in the array employee is the same as a valid id of my Employees collection.

If the employees in the array do not match a valid employee id the api should return an error response with a message that says `No employees with id ${employee}`

But for some reason i am getting undefined in my console.

Comment: `return` doesn't end `map` and won't return from a parent function

Comment: @Konrad so what should i do instead?

Comment: Use for each loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the employees from db in a loop is not a good solution, it will have performance problems.

So instead you can get all the employees once using $in operator, and apply the logic in the code.

You can do something like this:

```
    // Verify that the employees exist
    const foundEmploees = await Employee.find({
        _id: { $in: employees },
    });

    const foundEmploeesIds = foundEmploees.map((f) => f._id.toString());
    const errors = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        if (!foundEmploeesIds.includes(employees[i])) {
            errors.push(`Employees not found with id of ${employees[i]}`);
        } else {
            const emp = foundEmploees.find(
                (e) => e._id.toString() === employees[i]
            );

            if (emp.type !== 'manager') {
                errors.push(`Employees is not manager ${employees[i]}`);
            }
        }
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse(errors.join(','), 404));
    }
```